# How to serve static Google Maps for mobile, but dynamic for desktop?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, cross-browser, media-queries, progressive-enhancement

**What approaches are there for hiding [Google's Static Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) on wider viewports, while displaying the dynamic [Google JavaScript Maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/) instead?**

It is common to build mobile-first websites, enhanced through CSS media queries for larger viewports.

When it comes to maps, static ones are [arguably better for mobile UX](http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/adaptive-maps/) (smartphones too). But you might decide that for larger viewports (computer displays and even tablets), the interactive/dynamic maps may be better for your users — depending on the purpose of the website.

What criteria are important to use to choose the best approach to combine the two? What should one be careful with?

I have not been able to find a conclusive answer, but here is my research so far:

---

[One author suggested](http://fragility.us/2010/09/fallback-content-and-google-maps-api-version-3/) in 2010 that a fallback option is built into the JavaScipt API:

> The basic premise here is that the API replaces the content of the
>   `map_canvas` container with the map display. So, why not just add some
>   fallback content to that container?

Modifying his code, I can insert an image inside the `div` that will become the JS-enabled Google Maps. In this case, the image is from Static Maps V2:

```
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%">
    <img src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=Berkeley,CA&zoom=14&size=400x400&sensor=false">
  </div>
</body>
```

However, that does not disable JavaScript Maps on smartphones — simply provides a fallback for devices without JS.

---

[Another author](http://24ways.org/2010/finding-your-way-with-static-maps/) (also in 2010) also suggests to use a single line of jQuery to hide that image — the updates code for V3 would likely be:

```
$('#map_canvas img').remove();
```

But that also does nothing to disable Google's JS Maps on narrow-viewport devices (smartphones).

---

Both of those guides are from 2010 — likely using V2 of Google Maps? (I even came across [another author's guide from 2009](http://www.supersonicfeet.com/article/progressively-enhanced-google-maps-for-your-website) using some clever regex, but he is yet to update to "the new way [V3] of doing things".)

Answer (score 1):

The second approach(hiding the image) is  absolutely useless, the image will be replaced anyway when the map loads.

The first approach looks good, all you need is a condition at the start of initialize(), where you filter "small" devices and leave the function. It may look like that:

```
if(Math.min(screen.width,screen.height)<768){
        return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Interesting — so your suggested code is basically a 'media query' via JS? Will it work in older browsers?

Comment: screen.width/height has been introduced in JS Version 1.2(1997) , it will work in any browser that is supported by the maps-API .

Comment: Since 1997 means: [basically on every browser](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Versions), thanks! **I don't see any drawbacks with your method**, so I'll implement it and report back